# Making predictions using a Prediction Interval

Tags: prediction-interval

I have a group of observations with measured variables: *A*, *B*, *c* and *d*.

I want to predict *A* using: $f(A)=\beta_0c+ \beta_1d$. I usually get a prediction interval ($PI_\hat{A}$) using bootstrapping.

I also want to predict *B* using: $g(B)=\beta_2c+ \beta_3d + \beta_4A$.

In a real application, I'm mostly interested in using $g(B)$ but, besides the training data, I usually don't have an observed *A*, but a $\hat{A}$ (or more precisely a $PI_\hat{A}$).

Basically my question is if this is a valid approach.
Fit $g()$ with the observed *A*, and then predict $\hat{B}$ (actually $PI_\hat{B}$) using $\hat{A}$ ($PI_\hat{A}$).

Should I have some special considerations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have $A$ and $\hat{A}$ is just a linear combination of $c$ and $d$, the presence of $c$ and $d$ in your model for $B$ will make $\hat{A}$ redundant; any value it had in predicting $B$ via a regression model will be entirely subsumed by $c$ and $d$; put another way, your model will be perfectly collinear. The additional sums of squares to $\hat{A}$ (given $c$ and $d$ are in the model) should be 0 (up to rounding error).

Further, $\hat{A}$ is not the real variable, but one estimated with error (if you resampled your original data the $\hat{A}$ values would change). So this is not even a suitable variable for an ordinary regression model; it's more an errors-in-variables situation.

[There *might* be some way to get some predictive value out of this sort of setup, but you'd probably want to frame the issue in a different way and it would almost certainly involve some kind of regularization.]

Comment: What if the models were not linear? Do you think I might get some extra value? What do you mean by regularisation?

Comment: For nonlinear models, quite possibly yes, though it depends on the forms of the relationships. Regularization (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_%28mathematics%29)) would include things like shrinkage of parameters toward 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar approach to what I use. The difference comes down whether you want to explain or predict. Time series analysis is great for predicting, but regression is great for explaining. The two provide answers to different questions, i.e., "what" vs "why".

Sometimes you can use 1 model to answer both questions, i.e., regression of time series data, although this is inefficient and less accurate. Why use a regression model when time series forecasting will suffice other than to understand the impact of the coefficients on the process?

A more thorough treatment can be found at:

http://www.galitshmueli.com/system/files/Stat%20Science%20published.pdf